# sqlite3 shortens float value

Tags: sqlite, swift

I do a simple:

latitude:String = String.fromCString(UnsafePointer(sqlite3_column_text(statement, 11)))!

The value in the Database is "real". 
In the database I have
51.234183426424316 (verified using Firefox'SQLite Manager)

With the above I get in my String only:
51.2341834264243
(the last two digits are missing with is not acceptable working with coordinates)

Any explanations? Solutions?

Comment: Why is it stored as a `real` if you are expecting it as a `string`?  Should you be storing it as a `text`?  Or can you use the `sqlite3_column_double` function?

Comment: Its given by the database which is imported and not under my control. I will try column_double

Answer (score 2):

SQLite stores such numbers as as 64-bit IEEE floating-point numbers, which have a significand precisions of 53 bits, which corresponds to about 15-17 decimal digits.

How to format such a number for display is a different question.
If you want to have control over it, get the original value with [sqlite3_column_double()](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/column_blob.html), and convert it to a string yourself.

<sup>(And you are complaining about a difference that is smaller than the wavelength of visible light ...)</sup>